# SQL 2005 Database diagram support objects cannot be installed because this database does not have a valid owner

Tags: sql-server

I have two databases, production and stage. I am getting the error message in the title of this post when I click "Database Diagrams" for production, but on stage I don't get an error.

I've researched this message, and I've found posts such as this:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200223073542/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/shahed/archive/2007/11/19/116940.aspx)

They pretty much say to change the owner of my database to sa. I'm not convinced this is the issue, though, because both production and stage databases have the same owner (not sa), but I only get this error for production.

Does anyone else know how else to resolve this error message?

Comment: It's easy enough to test if the current owner is the issue, isn't it?  Change the owner to sa, if the problem goes away, then the owner was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> both production and stage databases
>   have the same owner (not sa), but I
>   only get this error for production.

That usually is the very source of the problem: a database created on one machine is restored on a different machine where the SID of the original creator is no longer valid. Change the owner to a valid one:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[<dbname>] TO sa;
```

Comment: I ran "EXEC sp_helpdb" and saw that the owner was what I expected, for example "myuser".

I ran this query: "EXEC sp_changedbowner 'myuser'", where "myuser" is the exact user I copied from the results of the sp_helpdb command, and now it's working right. Maybe this has to do with it getting the right SID that you mentioned?

Comment: Hmm... If sp_helpdb was capable of identifying 'myuser' correctly, then the dbo SID must had been a valid one, otherwise is not possible for SQL to figure out on its own that '1-5-002348778..' (ie. a SID) realy stands for 'myuser'.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error. In my case, I had existing Diagrams but could not view them on account of this error. I remembered that I had changed the name of the server a week or so ago. After renaming the computer, SQL Server (2012) apparently correctly began using the correct underlying local user object in the Logins section of Security. So, from appearances, the database had a valid owner. But the name of the security account wasn't changed - the username  of the owner was correctly **localputer\localuser** but the SQL account name was **local-puter\localuser** (the original name of the server). I renamed the account name to **localputer\localuser** and everything went back to normal. I did not need to issue an ALTER AUTH ON DB.